# T-SQL Query help: joining 2 different detail tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

this might be an easy one for all SQL experts...
I have a DB with the 3 main tables and would like to join two detail tables with a different sum of result sets. See details below...

```
Customer
-------------
ID
NAME
...

Projects
-------------
ID
CustomerID
ProjectName
ProjectStatus
...

Orders
-------------
ID
CusomterID
OrderDate
...
```

Now I would like to do a query which returns all Customers who have open projects (1 or more) and their last 5 orders grouped by customer.

Result could look like this

```
Customer1
Project Build website 
Project Do SEO
Orders:
2013-04-13 10.000$
2012-01-20  5.000$
2011-10-11  2.000$

Customer2
Project update system 

Orders:
2012-01-20  5.000$
2011-10-11  2.000$

.... and so on
```

So orders and projects have no relation and they can have not necessarily the same amount of rows. This is where I stuck because a query returns just one table with sum of all subqueries.

Or would it be better to run seperate queries?

I am using T-SQL with SERVER 2008R2.

Maybe I am just thinking to complicated but any help would be fantastic...

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do this in Reporting Services?

Comment: How projects and orders tables are connected? I don't see related columns.

Comment: @Justin: They're not (other than via Customer) - *"orders and projects have no relation"*.

Comment: If they are not connected, if customer has more than one open project, same 5 orders gonna duplicate for each project. Because I see in results you wanna and Project info...

Comment: @Justin: that's exactly the point why I am asking =)... so any pointers would be fantastic

Comment: @MarkBannister Reporting Services is no option at the moment and they do also rely on queries, don't they?

Comment: The display stuff should be handled in your application/display layer.  Building reports like this (breaking it up by customer etc) is not something that is easily or best done in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
SELECT c.NAME,
       p.ProjectName,
       o.*
FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN Projects p
  ON p.CustomerID = c.ID
LEFT JOIN Orders o
  ON o.CusomterID = c.ID
WHERE p.ProjectStatus = 'Open'
AND o.ID IN (SELECT TOP 5 o2.ID
             FROM Orders o2
             WHERE o2.CusomterID = c.ID
             ORDER BY o2.OrderDate Desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

The formatting of the output (issues such as Customer headings, project section headings, order section headings etc.) is best handled at an application layer (for example, within SSRS reports, ASP etc).

You can return all of the *data* required in a single query like this:

```
select c.NAME CustomerName, sq.*
from Customers c
join (select CustomerID, ID ProjectID, ProjectName, ProjectStatus, 
             'Projects' RecType, null OrderID, null OrderDate, null OrderValue
      from Projects
      union all
      select CustomerID, null ProjectID, null ProjectName, null ProjectStatus,
             'Orders' RecType, ID OrderID, OrderDate, OrderValue
      from Orders) sq
  on c.ID = sq.CustomerID
order by sq.CustomerID, sq.RecType desc, sq.ProjectID, sq.OrderID
```